# Opencart product sku on order maill?

Tags: php, twig, opencart

I need to have SKU on order confirmation in the email the user receive `"OC 3.0.3.2"`. 
I've tried to implement this solution that found in other site but it only display a blank space.
[image]

In `catalog/controller/mail/order.php file`

- Find each `$this->load->model('tool/upload');`
- Add below `$this->load->model('catalog/product');`
- Find each `$data['products'][] = array(`
- Add above `$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($order_product['product_id']);`
- Find each `'model'    => $order_product['model'],`
- Add below `'sku'     => $product_info['sku'],`

Then, in `catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/order_add.twig file`

- Find `<td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;">{{ product.model }}</td>`
- Add below `{{ product.sku }}`

How can I solve this issue as soon as possible?

Answer (score 0):

In catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/order_add.twig file

Find:

```
<td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;">{{ text_model }}</td>
```

Add Below:

```
<td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;">{{ text_sku }}</td>
```

Find:

```
<td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;">{{ product.model }}</td>
```

Add Below:

```
<td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;">{{ product.sku }}</td>
```

Find:

```
<td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;" colspan="4"><b>{{ total.title }}:</b></td>
```

Change to:

```
<td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;" colspan="5"><b>{{ total.title }}:</b></td>
```

If your controller file is correct you should get your desired result.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know if the controller do its things

Comment: if you add all your mentioned code in "catalog/controller/mail/order.php" file `public function add($order_info, $order_status_id, $comment, $notify) {`  section, it should work. Just after all you edit do not forget refresh modifications and clear cache in admin dashboard... blue gear icon in the upper right corner.